# Advice - How to implement the same code with different parameters

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, enums

I would like an advice. My project have a lot of equals methods with different values, and i would like to do a single method that does the same.

The methods are this:

```
private void Enum1()
{   
    Console.WriteLine(Enum.GetValue(ENUM1.Code));
    Console.WriteLine(Enum.GetValue(ENUM1.Info));
}

private void Enum2()
{   
    Console.WriteLine(Enum.GetValue(ENUM2.Code));
    Console.WriteLine(Enum.GetValue(ENUM2.Info));
}

private void Enum3()
{   
    Console.WriteLine(Enum.GetValue(ENUM3.Code));
    Console.WriteLine(Enum.GetValue(ENUM3.Info));
}
```

This is the enums:

```
public enum ENUM1
{
    Code = 1,
    Info = 3
}

public enum ENUM2
{
    Code = 91,
    Info = 4
}

public enum ENUM3
{
    Code = 6,
    Info = 27
}
```

There is only a way to create a method by inserting the input type of enum to use? maybe a similar solution of this:

```
private void General("ENUM1")
{   
    var type = ENUM1;

    switch (p)
    {
        case "ENUM1":
            type = ENUM1;
        case "ENUM2":
            type = ENUM2;
        case "CASALINGHI":
            type = ENUM3;

        default:
            type = ENUM1;
        }

    Console.WriteLine(Enum.GetValue(type.Code));
    Console.WriteLine(Enum.GetValue(type.Info));
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I don't think enums are the best choice here. Consider creating a class or struct with the properties `code` and `info`. Then all your different enums can be represented as instances of the same class; and you can simple create a method yourclass.writeToConsole() that accomplishes the same as all your static methods

Comment: I know , but i use this because in reality each enum has its string value `StringValue("n|11:5|0")] Code = 1,`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something like this is what you are looking for:

```
private void General<T>()
{
   var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(T));
   foreach(var value in values)
       Console.WriteLine(value);
}

General<Enum1>();
General<Enum2>();
General<Enum3>();
```

Or this, depending on how you want to use it:

```
private void General(Type enumType)
{
   var values = Enum.GetValues(enumType);
   foreach(var value in values)
       Console.WriteLine(value);
}

General(typeof(Enum1));
General(typeof(Enum2));
General(typeof(Enum3));
```

Comment: And the parameter? I must have a parameter to choose which ENUM (ENUM1,ENUM2,ENUM3) print.

Comment: You have the option. Is the type parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you keep using enums, when you can easily use classes? Read more about **Object-Oriented** programming.

Create a single class:

```
public class MyEnum
{
    public int Code
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public int Info
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public string Display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this.Code);
        Console.WriteLine(this.Info)
    }

    //
    // This will keep your enums static, available from any method
    //
    private static List<MyEnum> _globals = new List<MyEnum();

    public static List<MyEnum> Globals ()
    {
        if (this._globals.Count == 0)
        {
            this._globals.Add(new MyEnum(){ Code = 1, Info = 3 });
            this._globals.Add(new MyEnum(){ Code = 91, Info = 4 });
            this._globals.Add(new MyEnum(){ Code = 6, Info = 27 });
        }

        return this._globals;
    }
}
```

After this you can easily print out all the enums with the following code:

```
foreach (MyEnum* en in MyEnum.Globals())
{
    en.Display();
}
```

Please look into solutions similar to this one, since your enum's obviously represent some data.